# My workout can't get the necessary permissions

Tags: android, wifi, android-studio-3.0, wifimanager

I transcribed this practice app from a sample site, but even so, the same transcribing did not succeed, I also searched on the Internet, but I did not get any results. This program is supposed to show a list of nearby Wi-Fis. but it doesn't work

This is the state of my code

main Activity.java

```
package com.example.ch;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView wifiList;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    WifiReciver reciverwifi;

    @SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wifiList = findViewById(R.id.wifilist);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        Button btnscanwifi = findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turning wifi on..,",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        btnscanwifi.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"if level statment is received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reciverwifi = new WifiReciver(wifiManager,wifiList);
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
                registerReceiver(reciverwifi, intentFilter);

                wifiManager.startScan();

            }else {

                reciverwifi = new WifiReciver(wifiManager,wifiList);
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

                intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);


                registerReceiver(reciverwifi, intentFilter);

                wifiManager.startScan();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onPostResume(){
        super.onPostResume();
        reciverwifi =new WifiReciver(wifiManager,wifiList);
        IntentFilter intentFilter =new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(reciverwifi,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        getwifi();
    }

    public void getwifi(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }else {
            wifiManager.startScan();
        }
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(reciverwifi);
    }

    public  void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permission,@NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permission,grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                wifiManager.startScan();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

wifiReciver.java

```
package com.example.ch;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class WifiReciver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    StringBuilder sb;
    ListView wifiDeviceList;
    Context context;

    public WifiReciver(WifiManager wifiManager,ListView wifiDeviceList){
        this.wifiManager =wifiManager;
        this.wifiDeviceList =wifiDeviceList;
    }
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent ){
        String action =intent.getAction();
        if(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(
                action
        )&& ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            sb =new StringBuilder();
            List<ScanResult> wifilist =wifiManager.getScanResults();
            ArrayList<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ScanResult scanResult :wifilist){
                sb.append("wifi_object").append(scanResult.SSID).append(".").append(scanResult.capabilities);
                deviceList.add(scanResult.SSID+"."+scanResult.capabilities);

            }
            Toast.makeText(context,sb,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            wifiDeviceList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.ch">
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Ch"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_gravity = "bottom"
        android:layout_margin = "15dp"
        android:text = "Scan WiFi"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wifilist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried all the ways I knew to improve this code, but I don't know where the problem is

logcat error

```
Permission violation - startScan not allowed for uid=10323, packageName=com.example.ch, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10323 has no location permission
```

If anyone has a better idea that can help me, I will be happy